# Exporting video to .mov in Blender 2.79

Tags: video, encoding

In the past, Blender (at least the Mac version) has had the ability to encode video files as .mov, the format used by Quicktime Player. However, with Blender 2.79 this feature seems to have vanished, for both the Internal and Cycles render engines. The release log happens to have the entry "Video encoding settings have been simplified, along with the addition of a Constant Rate Factor (CRF) mode" which I suppose could be the cause.

Does anyone know what happened—whether it is the aformentioned reason or something else—and how to export videos as Quicktime .mov in Blender 2.79?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In version 2.79 Video encoding settings have been simplified.
Read:https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.79/More_Features

Quicktime (.mov) is a [Container](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/data_system/files/media/video_formats.html#video-containers).

Choose [FFmpeg video](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FFmpeg) in the output panel.

Select **Quicktime** as **Container** in the [Encoding](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/output/video.html?highlight=encoding#encoding-panel) panel.

[image]